# Crontab webcam usage

Tags: cron, webcam, archlinux

So I have this issue on archlinux with crontab. I have a python script which when run opens a webcam with detection AI. I have tried it outside of the crontab several times and it runs perfectly but when I try to schedule it and run with crontab I can't see webcam opening. I am guessing it might be because of the privileges of the crontab or maybe some dependencies. Any help is appreciated. Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Can you share the crontab line, and with what command you scheduled it (e.g. `crontab -e`) ?

Comment: It is: * * * * * home/test.sh: test.sh is basically a bash script that runs the python script at the directory the script is: python script: /path/detect.py --source 0: source 0 is used for webcam

Comment: From the cron tag: Questions about configuring cron for systems or administration are OFF TOPIC.

Answer (score 1):

When you run from shell, e.g. bash, it calls .bash_profile, which you might have setup some environment variables.  Therefore, your webcam program work.  To proof my point, rename the .bash_profile temporary to other filename, and it should fail in shell prompt like crontab as well.

If above is valid, then you need to add necessary environment variables into your program, e.g. shell script.  This is a standard practice for all programs triggered by UNIX crontab

Comment: Well yes, that was what I also was thinking but this script I am trying to work with is going to eventually be executed in raspi board so maybe there is some way to run it there that would not work in arch?

Comment: If the program that you configure to run in crontab is already a script, then can you modify the script to add necessary environment variables?  You don't need to create another shell script, or program by modifying existing script.

Firstly, prove that your webcam program needs some environment variables by removing all environment variables from interactive shell login session.  Let's confirm we are in the correct direction first